# Que diferencia hay entre ExecuteReader y executeNonQuery?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Necesito respuestas de otros

Comment: Hola Adrian. Recuerda que este sitio ayuda  a resolver problemas concretos que tengas, no somos un buscador avanzado. has de investigar y leer para determinar las diferencias y si hay algo concreto que no te quede claro, preguntarlo siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **ExecuteScalar ()** solo devuelve el valor de la primera columna de la primera fila de su consulta.
- **ExecuteReader ()** devuelve un objeto que puede iterar sobre todo el conjunto de resultados manteniendo solo un registro en la memoria a la vez.
- **ExecuteNonQuery ()** no devuelve datos: solo el número de filas afectadas por una inserción, actualización o eliminación.

Además, puede ver el tipo **DbDataAdapter** , que incluye un método `Fill()` que le permite descargar todo el conjunto de resultados en un objeto **DataTable** o **DataSet** , así como varias otras habilidades.

Finalmente, este es un buen momento para familiarizarse con MSDN . Para esto está hecha la documentación: usted tiene los nombres de los métodos. Ve a buscarlos.

Esta respuesta es una traducción de otra pregunta en [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

[Fuente/Pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058970/when-to-use-executescalar-executereader-executenonquery)

Comment: Muy entendible gracias ya aclare mis dudas

Comment: Hola Fran. Gracias por responder, pero esta pregunta parece que con una busqueda en google y un poco de lectura él mismo podria entenderlo. De no entenderlo, deberia especificar en la pregunta qué dudas concretas tiene. Para preguntas asi, comentaselo y pulsa en reportar para que entre en la cola de revisión. Un saludo